# canvas push object failed

Tags: javascript, canvas

each time when I am reviewing and trying to re-write my code I always got errors and some unexpected issues. I am making a function object called `draw()` and trying to push it 20 times into an empty array for the animate purpose. the code is as follows:

```
function draw(){
            var r = 20;
            var x = Math.random()*canvas.width - r;
            var y = Math.random()*canvas.height - r;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,r,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.fillStyle='yellow';
            ctx.fill();
        }


        myArray = [];

    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        myArray.push(draw());
    }

    function animate(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
            myArray[i];
        }
    }

    animate();
```

When I am checking `myArray`object in the console, it just popped out 20 objects with `undefined` value, which means there is totally empty inside `myArray`object. I am stuck with this for 2 hours could someone could tell me where I go wrong with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myArray.push(draw())` *calls* the `draw()` function immediately and puts its return value (`undefined`) into the array. You probably want to push a reference to the function, so omit the `()`:

```
myArray.push(draw);
```

Then, in your for loop, to call the functions from the array you need parentheses:

```
myArray[i]();
```

Pushing the *same* function seems a bit pointless, because you could just directly call the function from your loop without using the array, but I assume you want to set up for the possibility of running some predefined sequence of several different functions that aren't shown.

Anyway, the following demo shows the above changes working in the context of your full code:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw() {
  var r = 20;
  var x = Math.random() * canvas.width - r;
  var y = Math.random() * canvas.height - r;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.fill();
}

myArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  myArray.push(draw);   // this line changed
}

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i]();       // this line changed
  }
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks@nnnnnn now I got this, passing with reference should not include the () since there is no-return value within my function object. I am just trying to review what i learned and keep coding some random stuff to get the solid feelings with canvas stuff:D thanks for your reply!

Comment: Even if your function did return a value, you still want to use a *reference* to the function, you don't want to call it yet. So don't use `()` at that point. Only use `()` at the point where you want to call it. (The exception would be if the return value from your function was itself a reference to some function.)